# Ошибка при компиляции в Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

Установил Code::Blocks 16.01; запускаю любой проект- выдает ошибку!Выскакивают следующие окна: [после нажатия собрать и запустить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mREqF.jpg)
[image: и еще окно после нажатия кнопки нет]. Подскажите пожалуйста,как устранить? От имени администратора запускал, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Это потому, что у файла расширение ads. И, вероятно, вы открываете не проект, а просто файл. Должно быть расширение c, cc, cpp.

Comment: + к расширению: вы код-то зачем такой написали? Вряд ли он соберётся и с правильным расширением  файла.